# Can gravitational waves resonate?

Tags: waves, reflection, interference, resonance, gravitational-waves

Can gravitational waves resonate? - Perhaps by creating standing wave interference in a cavity?

Could that feasibly happen either in nature or by engineering?

Comment: Related: [Since there are gravitational lenses are there gravitational mirrors?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52167/since-there-are-gravitational-lenses-are-there-gravitational-mirrors)

Comment: For reference, this author seems to claim to have coined the term "Heisenberg-Coulomb effect". https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.114.081104

Answer (score 6):

It is theoretically predicted that superconducting layers might be able to act as reflectors through the so called Heisenberg-Coulomb effect. Out of these, you could of course form a cavity able to contain a gravitational wave in principle.

This effect has, to my knowledge, not yet been experimentally tested, although several tests have been proposed, see, for example, [Do mirrors for gravitational waves exist?](http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.0661v10)(ArXiv link).

Comment: +1 Very interesting; I had never heard of the Heisenberg-Coulomb effect.

Comment: So it doesn't look like that paper was ever published In a refereed journal. I've never heard of their claims, and it doesn't seem to have had follow on publications by others. I looked at the paper, too long to read critically unless one believes it's real. And other than that paper and references made to it in PSE, I don't see anything on a so called Heisenberg Coulomb effect.