# Are condensates of gravitational waves possible?

Tags: gravity, gravitational-waves, bose-einstein-condensate

Bose-Einstein condensation has been observed in a multitude of physical systems ([cold atoms](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/269/5221/198), [exciton-polaritons](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/298/5591/199), [magnons](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v443/n7110/full/nature05117.html) to name a few). Notably in 2010 a BEC of [photons](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v468/n7323/full/nature09567.html) was experimentally detected.

Photons are spin 1 bosons. A natural question to ask is would be if a BEC of **gravitons** (spin 2 bosons) is theoretically possible? If so, what possible effects could it have on cosmology?

Comment: To do something like the scheme described, one would need a gravitational wave resonating cavity. Therefore these questions are relevant: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/169550/can-gravitational-waves-resonate/169711#169711 
http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52167/since-there-are-gravitational-lenses-are-there-gravitational-mirrors

Comment: In addition, some matter that can couple strongly to them is required, in lieu  of the dye... I can't say that this is impossible in principle but I believe it would be an extremely exotic situation.